# Ubuntu in org : best practices

Tags: package-management, system-installation, user-management

Is there a canonical document of what are a few things to use Ubuntu in an organisation? We are an IT company. Our office laptops have windows installed. I want to experiment with Ubuntu. At home i use Ubuntu but there is no anti virus or management software. I understand that this is a broad question but is there some place to start ? any in use org that shares its practices?

A mgt software to know for example of people have changed their passwords in the last x weeks or what software they have installed?
To do a remote login to any laptop ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such "canonical" document.

There are many, many testimonials and experiences shared on various blogs and videos around the internet showing how folks use Ubuntu in their organization.

Comment: Can you point me to a few? Or the Google searches that yield good links to them